# how to get setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER) effect using setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX)

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

In Android using ImageView and Matrix, I want to scale an image to fit in the display area.
Then using pinch, a user can zoom the image.
Using `setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)` I can fit my image in display area. But when I use `setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX)`, to start zooming the image, the image gets reset to default size.

So my question is how to find a scale matrix which will give same effect as 
`setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mMatrix.setRectToRect` and `Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER` with your image coordinates and your view coordinates as the source and destination rectangles.

```
mMatrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0,0,mImageView.getMeasuredWidth(),mImageView.getMeasuredHeight()),new RectF(0,0,mImageView.getParent().getMeasuredWidth(),mImageView.getParent().getMeasuredHeight()),Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
```