# How to fit image to center while using TouchImageView?

Tags: image, touch, zooming, scale, pan

I have a gallery application that needs to zoom and pan. Instead of using default imageview , I found a sample touchmageview on internet and copied it. I called my images with TouchImageView and now i can zoom and pan the images that I called from my drawable folder. Then I added gallery to my project. Now the problem is that I can not fit the images to the screen.When I use scaletype.center then it fits the image to the screen but now zoom and pan features are not working. This is my gallerylistener ;

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(Display.this, "Your selected position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // show the selected Image


                       img.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                       img.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);

                    }
                });
```

As you see , if I add       img.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); then the TouchImageView class doesn't work and I am not able to zoom and pinch and pan etc.. It only display the image. When I delete this code , then I can zoom but then when I change the picture to another one , the new one has the previous image's size. But I want to fit them to the center. Is there any way to reset the scaletype before calling the new image ?

By the way I have only one imageview in xml.

There is a similar question on this link but the solution did not work for me.
[how to get setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER) effect using setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766052/how-to-get-setscaletypeimageview-scaletype-fit-center-effect-using-setscaletyp)

Comment: Any solution u got?